# how could I download file in mobile

Tags: javascript, mobile

require:I need to download files from server in mobile.

question:
In pc:

```
<a href="file.url">
    click me to download
</a>
```

and

```
<a @click="func"></a> 

<script>
   function func(){
      var myFrame= document.createElement(“iframe”); 
      myFrame.src = “url”;
      myFrame.style.display = “none”; 
    document.body.appendChild(myFrame);
   }
</script>
```

botn works well,but it can't work well in mobile,how can I realize it?

Comment: What's the iframe code, how does it relate to the link? What file type is it?

Comment: Thanks for your patience.I understood why it can't work.The reason is it is in wechat and the built-in browser shields the download function.